# SSRS Column graph with sum of hours of all child levels shown under parent

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, recursive-query

I would like to kindly ask for help with SELECT in MS Reporting Services. I am creating a graph report (column type), where columns should be hours spent on project (sum of all hours spent on parent report, its children and their children).
The concept is:
First report is [a column graph, where values are all hours spent on projects and their children by months (axis x) and series group is based on type of issue where hours were spent on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aiZ3.png).

Second report is the one I have problem with - drill down on month should show on axis x name of main parent reports and in column hours spent on it and all their children. Based on parent ID and month there is drill down to third report - all children on first level of selected parent report with sum of hours spent on them and their children.

[The source tables are stuctured as on picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNNJB.png), I use LEFT JOIN in SELECTs because there can be parents without issues and hours, but I need their children have some (and I show parent's name). Parent ID is only for direct parent not for the main one (it is possible to recognize that one, parent ID is NULL). There is no level sign to recognize, how deep in hierarchy you are. And there is no rule for how many levels project can have.
For third level I have created a SELECT, which goes deeper and deeper:

```
WITH hierarchy AS (SELECT id, parent_id, name
                   FROM dbo.projects AS p
                   WHERE        (id = @id)
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT  p.id, p.parent_id, p.name
                   FROM  dbo.projects AS p INNER JOIN hierarchy AS h ON p.parent_id = h.id)
SELECT        @id AS pid, hierarchy_1.parent_id, hierarchy_1.id, hierarchy_1.name, i.tracker_id AS fronta_id, t.hours, t.spent_on, t.tmonth, f.name AS fronta
 FROM            hierarchy AS hierarchy_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                          dbo.issues AS i ON hierarchy_1.id = i.project_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.time_entries AS t ON i.id = t.issue_id INNER JOIN
                          dbo.trackers AS f ON i.tracker_id = f.id
 WHERE        (t.tmonth = @month)
```

I have tried to use this for second report, but everything failed. I have searched a lot for possible solutions, but unfortunately I usually ended by grouping hours under main parents.
I have got an advice to go from last child, sum all hours and go higher. But in the end I am not able to specify main parent by which should be grouped the chart.

Thank you very much in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WITH hierarchy AS (SELECT id as id, id as child_id
                   FROM dbo.projects AS p
                   WHERE        (id = @id)
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT  h.id, p.id
                   FROM  dbo.projects AS p INNER JOIN hierarchy AS h ON p.parent_id = h.child_id
                  )

SELECT        hierarchy_1.id AS pid, p.name as p_name, hierarchy_1.child_id AS child_pid, i.tracker_id AS fronta_id, t.hours, t.spent_on, t.tmonth,f.name AS fronta
FROM          hierarchy AS hierarchy_1
    INNER JOIN dbo.projects AS p ON P.id=hierarchy_1.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.issues AS i ON hierarchy_1.id = i.project_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.time_entries AS t ON i.id = t.issue_id 
        INNER JOIN dbo.trackers AS f ON i.tracker_id = f.id
 WHERE        (t.tmonth = @month)
```

To calculate SUM, replace the SELECT line with this one and add a GROUP BY line

```
SELECT        hierarchy_1.id AS pid, first(p.name) as p_name, i.tracker_id AS fronta_id, sum(t.hours), MIN(t.spent_on), MIN(t.tmonth)), MIN(f.name) AS fronta
GROUP BY      hierarchy_1.id, i.tracker_id
```